# Why won't this Bootstrap 4 Navbar not create equal width menu items?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navigation, nav

I have a Bootstrap 4 navbar with six nav items and an inline search.

The menu items are squashed on the left side of the menu (horizontally), there is a large gap of empty space, and on the far right is the search box.

[Here is a codeply](https://codeply.com/v/dR6NwJoeG4) with the source code I'm struggle with (HTML/CSS). (Or see below for the complete code)

Unfortunately, while there is [documentation on accomplishing this with navs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/navs/#fill-and-justify) there [isn't for navbars](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/navbar/).

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

```html
<div class="page">
    <div class="lqd-header-menu">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-controls="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle Navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul id="menu-primary-menu" class="navbar-nav mr-auto nav-justified">
                    <li id="menu-item-32" class="nav-item"><a title="New Here" href="https://one.wordpress.test/newhere/" class="nav-item nav-link">New Here</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-5150" class="nav-item"><a title="Messages" href="https://one.wordpress.test/messages/" class="nav-item nav-link">Messages</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-4858" class="nav-item"><a title="Groups" href="https://one.wordpress.test/groups" class="nav-item nav-link">Groups</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-29" class="nav-item"><a title="Serve" href="https://one.wordpress.test/serve" class="nav-item nav-link">Serve</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-28" class="nav-item"><a title="Family" href="https://one.wordpress.test/family/" class="nav-item nav-link">Family</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-442598" class="nav-item"><a title="Give" href="https://one.wordpress.test/give" class="nav-item nav-link">Give</a></li>
                </ul>
                <form method="get" class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" id="search-form" action="https://one.wordpress.test/" role="search">
                    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" name="s" aria-label="Search">
                </form>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.page {
    box-shadow: 0 0 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 1280px;
}

.lqd-header-menu {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #14a7e0;
}

.lqd-header-menu ul li {
    border-left: 1px solid #fff;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #fff;
}

/* Individual Menu Items */
.lqd-header-menu li a {
    color: #fff;
    /* Set Menu Item Links to White */
    display: block;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-family: 'Avenir Next Cyr W00 Bold', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

/* Removes Separator Before New Here */
.lqd-header-menu ul li:first-child {
    border: medium none;
}

.lqd-header-menu ul li:last-child {
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I used css flexbox ([codeply](https://www.codeply.com/p/gRfcQhXigc))

```html
<div class="page">
    <div class="lqd-header-menu">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-controls="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle Navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <a title="New Here" href="https://one.wordpress.test/newhere/" class="nav-item nav-link">New Here</a>
                <a title="Messages" href="https://one.wordpress.test/messages/" class="nav-item nav-link">Messages</a>
                <a title="Groups" href="https://one.wordpress.test/groups" class="nav-item nav-link">Groups</a>
                <a title="Serve" href="https://one.wordpress.test/serve" class="nav-item nav-link">Serve</a>
                <a title="Family" href="https://one.wordpress.test/family/" class="nav-item nav-link">Family</a>
                <a title="Give" href="https://one.wordpress.test/give" class="nav-item nav-link">Give</a>
                <form method="get" class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" id="search-form" action="https://one.wordpress.test/" role="search">
                    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" name="s" aria-label="Search">
                </form>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.collapse.navbar-collapse {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
.collapse.navbar-collapse a{
    color: white;
}
.page {
    box-shadow: 0 0 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 1280px;
}

.lqd-header-menu {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #14a7e0;
}

.lqd-header-menu ul li {
    border-left: 1px solid #fff;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #fff;
}

/* Individual Menu Items */
.lqd-header-menu li a {
    color: #fff;
    /* Set Menu Item Links to White */
    display: block;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-family: 'Avenir Next Cyr W00 Bold', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

/* Removes Separator Before New Here */
.lqd-header-menu ul li:first-child {
    border: medium none;
}

/* Adds Separator After Give */
.lqd-header-menu ul li:last-child {
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is helpful! I'd like to find out how to do it within BS4 if possible, it seems like this should be simple to do in BS4!

Comment: @DaveMackey Here is a way to do it using bootstrap's grid system instead: [Codeply](https://www.codeply.com/p/lrxYTh37io)

Comment: Thanks! This looks good on larger screens but doesn't resize itself to fit the screen width as the screen size shrinks (e.g. phones, some small tablets) and the menu runs off the right side of the screen.

Comment: Yeah it's not mobile friendly. You will either have to use the navbar collapsing feature, or using bootstrap's [grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) to create responsive rows.